# How to properly update parent component using React

Tags: reactjs

I see different variations of this question on SO, but nothing has really been clicking for me in my given situation. I am fairly new to React and I wanted to see what is considered the "React way" or best practice.

From a high level perspective I have a "User" table that has a button that triggers a modal for input and allows functionality to add a new user.

Here is my current tree of components:

```
.
└── UserLayout
    ├── AddNewUserButton 
        └── UserModal
    └── UserGrid
        └── UserGridBody
            └── UserGridRow
```

`UserLayout` is the component that does the initial `GET` of my users as a state and updates my children components being passed in as `props`.

`UserModal` is what handles the input and does a `POST` to my API.

My question is, how would I have my User table update after the `POST` from my `UserModal` component. I have seen examples of passing callback functions to the child components that set the state again, but in this situation I would have to do that through two levels of components and it makes me think that I am probably thinking about my state driven components improperly and I wanted to get some advice on what has held tried and true. What is best practice?

Let me know if it would be more helpful to post all my code. I didn't think it was necessary for this type of question, but if it would help illustrate my issue better, I can certainly do that.

Comment: Yes, the only viable "vanilla React-way" of doing this is to simply pass the component down via props. One component at a time. This works fine for one, perhaps two levels down. However, if your app is complex or if this scenario is very common you might want to take a look at libraries, such as [redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/). There are more libraries like this, but these two are the most common. They both have their pros and cons and you might want to do some research on each before you decide. You can also check out [tag:redux] and [tag:mobx] on SO. Good luck!

Comment: Just as Chris said, you could try using Flux, Redux or MobX for such scenarios where you have a deep flow of data.

Comment: @Chris - Thank you for the verification on my thoughts. I guess two layers isn't terrible, but definitely makes me more conscientious of maintaining my state properly (which is why I like working with react so much). Last question for you... Would it be best to push the latest user to my array of Users in the state? Or should I return all users again and reset my state that way?

Comment: One thing I noticed. Why is your user modal a child of user button?  You could have user layout handle the mechanics between the button and the display of your modal and then you would only have 1 layer to pass up to?

Comment: You can use the context if you don't want 2 layers and force update your component

Comment: @scapegoat17 You can't really just push because state is immutable. You'd need to pass in the new array. So create a copy of the existing one, add the new user to the copy, then pass in the new array.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks again! That is essentially what I meant about adding it to the existing state! If you are interested in the fake internet points feel free to post an answer and I will mark as the answer!

Comment: @maxwell - I would have to agree with you. It was definitely one thing i noted for refactor once i got this all working. Great catch and thank you!

Comment: @scapegoat17, thanks but I'll pass. There are similar questions out there, and I guess you could say this post is a duplicate to some extent and I don't want to post an answer to a dupe. I'd post a link but I don't feel like searching for it right now, hehe. Glad I could help regardless. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to pass callbacks in React and two-levels or even three is nothing exceptional. However when passing callbacks down the tree becomes tedious, or make things harder to trace later then having external state for storing data is a good idea. State can be then shared across all components in project without the need of having specific structure or passing data to make it work.

[This article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) may help you as well understanding when you have "faced a wall" when keeping local component state is adding too much complexity and becomes error prone. (Its about redux, but I think it can be also referenced when using other state management library like MobX as they try to solve the same problem)